# Does Yugabyte JSONB Keep the order of json properties?

Tags: yugabytedb

Is there any guarantee that JSONB keep the order of json properties in which they were inserted?

**Update**:
In Docs, I found it sort json keys for efficiency.

What should i do if i gonna a key always be the first one?

Answer (score 0):

> What should i do if i gonna a key always be the first one?

The option is to use `json` field in YSQL which only does validation on insert.

While on YCQL, you have to use `TEXT` column and do the conversion manually.

Comment: What if i put $ at the beginning  of key name which i want to be first field? It should work if it is sorting fields base on characters unicode(string sort).